# PowerBI Desktop Visualization Error when drilling down time: "The Field Values in your x-axis are mismatched."

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

**Program:** PowerBI Desktop

**Visualization Type:** Scatter Chart

**X Axis:** DATETIME formatted column (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) with Date Hierarchy automatically generated in Data Pane

**Y-Axis:** Numerical value to be visualized

**Problem:** Scatter Chart only works in YEAR level of X Axis. When trying to drill down, I am met with an error.. My dataset only has one unique time per row and the datatypes were checked in PowerQuery Editor to be correct.

> **Error:** *"The Field Values in your x-axis are mismatched. Set all the fields in your x-axis to 'Don't Summarize', or remove all fields except one."*

**Note:** If I aggregate my Y Axis values (such as aggregation by SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, etc.), I can drill down to all levels.

So, to sum it up, I wanted to visualize my data in Month, Date and Time level in a scatter chart. However, the program refuses to drop down below Year Level even though hierarchy is set. What might be the possible reason for the same?